# Cant launch app with new Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

My app work perfectly fine until I download new Xcode, now it stopped by error "signal SIGABRT" and point for this:

```
[PlaceHolder setDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79838900
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PlaceHolder setDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79838900'
```

I know, that information may not be enough to understand what's going on, but i have no idea where  to start search. If there was errors with setter methods, why my app works before? Is there any new changes that prevent app from launching?

`PlaceHolder` is an object, that hold properties (like image links, text etc.).
Also, there is a new "yellow" warning -  `Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'description' because it is 'read-write' but it will be synthesized 'read-only' via another property`

Comment: clean derevied data folder of your app -> Organizer -> Projects -> Your app.

Comment: 'description' is it field of you custom class? If you can rename it, do it, description seems to be used somewhere in os like a keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that you have defined a `description` property. Unfortunately `NSObject` already has a [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method. Since you are presumably not deliberately attempting to override this method in your subclass this is probably not a safe operation. It looks like under the iOS 7 SDK and Xcode 5 your property replaced the method on `NSObject`. In the iOS 8 SDK and Xcode 6 this is not the case (possibly due to changes in the way the `-description` method is defined) so you get different behavior.

Consider renaming this property to avoid such conflicts. `description` is a useful debugging tool and one you might not want to give up on this class accidentally.

Comment: Looks like `description` did become a property in iOS 8: http://www.redwindsoftware.com/blog/post/2014/08/20/NSObject-has-some-new-properties-in-iOS-8.aspx

Answer (score 8):

thank you very much for helping.

Description is a property of PlaceHolder class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
```

Problem was solved simply putting `@synthesize description;` in implementation (.m) file of PlaceHolder class. For some reason, new Xcode synthesise it via "read only" property, and that cause an SIGBART error, because app tried write to this property (which was readonly for some reason).

I hope that information might be helpful for someone, who face similar issue.

Comment: I was utilizing a property named "name" and was having the same problem. In this cause I am specifically utilizing my custom functionality of this variable (rather than overriding description), so this answer fixed my problem.

Comment: glad i could help you ColdLogic

Comment: How safe is this though? Would we ever run into problems for doing this?

Comment: @raulriera i think better solution is to avoid using description name, when u naming properties or ivars.